# Installing nvidia drivers causes computer to boot to command prompt

Tags: 10.10, nvidia

I have an Asus u30jc laptop, which comes with the Optimus prime graphics card switching technology that is now supported under 2.6.35, so I decided to give it a try. First I made sure the discrete graphics card was activated and then I installed the drivers proposed by the ubuntu software repository (nvidia-current).

However, after rebooting all I got was a command prompt.

My graphics card is a nvidia 310M. This is on Ubuntu 10.10 64 bits.

What can I do to diagnose/identify the source of this problem?

UPDATE: The messsages in my syslog tell me to check the xorg log:

```
Oct 11 12:42:59 u30jc-test gdm-binary[1095]: WARNING: GdmDisplay: display lasted 0.053144 seconds
Oct 11 12:42:59 u30jc-test gdm-simple-slave[1450]: WARNING: Unable to load file '/etc/gdm/custom.conf': No such file or directory
Oct 11 12:42:59 u30jc-test gdm-binary[1095]: WARNING: GdmDisplay: display lasted 0.038176 seconds
Oct 11 12:42:59 u30jc-test gdm-binary[1095]: WARNING: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached: check X server log for errors
```

Which I did. I found this message in my /var/log/Xorg.0.log :

```
Fatal server error:
[   113.540] no screens found
[   113.540]
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? If so how?

Comment: Not really. I read a report somewhere that, by blacklisting the intel driver and installing the nvidia one, you could boot using nvidia's proprietary drivers, but has never worked for me.

Best thing I managed to do was turn off the nvidia card using vga switcheroo.

There is information about that and more on : http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/. I subscribed to their mailing list and am following progresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully installed bumblebee in a Asus U30Jc and I can use the Intel card for the desktop and the nvidia card for graphics-hungry applications, like games, google-chrome, cuda programming, etc. Also, the external monitor management with the Intel card (gnome-display-properties) is better than with the nvidia closed-source drivers: it will remember your configuration for the different external screens (work, home, TV, etc). Have a look at the bumblebee section in this website: https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

```
sudo apt-get install git
# type password
git clone http://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee.git
cd bumblebee/
sudo ./install.sh
optirun glxgears
# check the speed and compare to running:
glxgears
# If you have google-chrome installed, you can try it with/without optirun and report the FPS values on the mailing list:
optirun google-chrome http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html
```

Comment: I have also installed bumblebee successfully on my laptop not more than 2 days ago. First time I ever got my nvidia card rendering anything under Linux, much thanks to the bumblebee guys for that.

Gotta watch out and make sure you are running a stable version though, as at first I got unlucky and installed a bugged version that kind of destroyed my setup.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to look is the file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Look for entries that start with `(EE)`.

Another good places are `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to issue

```
  sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

which should backup and recreate a working config file
this util gets installed as part of the nvidia driver install